# message undefined variable: news on view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP and CodeIgniter, and saw that there is many questions mentioning this and been trying them all but nothing seems to work. Everything is auto-loaded in configuration, the database is running and function for posting to database are working but writing to view page doesn't work at all. Except for displaying username, but for that I create a new variable on view page.

Controller

```
 public function ShowNews()
 {
     $data = array();
     $this->load->model('user');
     $data['news'] = $this->user->getNews();
     $this->load->vars($data);
}
```

Model

```
function getNews(){
    $q = $this->db->get('News');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        return $q->result();
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($news as $row) : ?>

<li><?php echo $row->Title;  ?> </li>
<li><?php echo $row->Date; ?></li>      

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the error EDIT ves to news

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: admin/Pocetna.php

Line Number: 64
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: admin/Pocetna.php

Line Number: 64
```

Using WAMP, NetBeans with CodeIgniter. I saw it has to be something with passing data from controller to view but I can't figure it out and been trying few days already, but always having problems.

Comment: 1) `ves` is not set anywhere. and 2) You haven't supplied an array of object array in your foreach.

Comment: ves is in my native language,i change ves to news when copying here

Comment: please post the calling for Shownews function

Comment: what calling, please explain???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing `$data` to your view. Your controller should be like this:

```
public function show_news()
{
    $this->load->model('user');

    $data = [];
    $data['news'] = $this->user->get_news();

    $this->load->view('news', $data);
}
```

Your view should also be checking if `$news` is `FALSE`, because you'll have some issues with `foreach` if you loop over the value `FALSE`. Your model should also be returning `result_array` not `result`, `foreach` cam't loop over objects..

```
public function get_news()
{
    $q = $this->db->get('News');

    return($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result_array() : FALSE;
}
```

Your view should look something like this:

```
<?php
    if($news !== FALSE)
    {
        foreach($news as $row)
        {
            echo "<li>{$row['title']}</li>";
            echo "<li>{$row['date']}</li>"; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No news to see here!";
    }
?>
```

Your title also doesn't link up with the error in the post, so that's the solution to the one in the title.

Comment: I forgot to change ves to news when copying here because variable ves is in my native language, so i change it so you can better understand......  Still getting the same mistake now in two rows

Comment: Yes, everything is as you said

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: admin/Pocetna.php

Line Number: 65 and 67

Comment: this:  65: if($news !== FALSE){ 67: foreach($news as $row).... it's not recognising $news

Comment: I have a feeling you haven't changed the controller code. What have you got in your show_news function

Comment: public function Show_news(){
                $this->load->model('user');
                $data = [];
                $data['news'] = $this->user->getNews();
  $this->load->view('admin/pocetna',$data);
    }

Comment: And the output from `var_dump($data); exit;` before the `$this->load->view`?

Comment: public function PrikaziVesti(){
                $this->load->model('korisnik');
                $data = [];
                $data['news'] = $this->korisnik->getVesti();
                var_dump($data); 
                exit();
  $this->load->view('admin/pocetna',$data);
    } like this? still getting the same

Comment: What's the output of that?

Comment: Nothing just a same php error is showing there is no output from that

Comment: Yes it's the right function, but still it's not recognising the variable news... There is a warning sign that says variable $news seems to be uninitialized

Comment: Please paste the error from the one with `var_dump` and `exit`

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: admin/Pocetna.php

Line Number: 65

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: admin/Pocetna.php

Line Number: 67

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: admin/Pocetna.php

Line Number: 67

Comment: You haven't saved the code or you have some sort of caching in place.

Comment: Everything is saved and it's should run, even delete all the data from table session so it can start a fresh page and still getting the same result

Comment: Well the `exit` isn't getting run, nor the `var_dump` you have something in place stopping it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH @Jordan Doyle!!!! problem solved, I'm little embarrassed but the problem was that i didn't call function in other function in controller...